# Emmet stopped working for CSS files in VS Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, emmet

I used to write CSS with emmet all the time. It stopped working all of a sudden.

In the image below, It can be seen that emmet has stopped giving suggestions when I type `m0`. It used to give a dropdown showing `margin: 0; Emmet Abbrevation` But It isn't showing now. I've tried many answers from Stackoverflow, but unfortunately nothing seems to solve the issue for me. It would be nice If someone helps me sort this out.

[image: Image showing CSS emmet not suggesting dropdowns]

**Settings.json**

```
{
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
        "markdown"
    ],
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    },
    "emmet.optimizeStylesheetParsing": true,
    "emmet.preferences": {},
    "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": true,
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {},
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.variables": {},
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    }
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true
}
```

Comment: hey, have you managed to solve this? can you share the solution of so. thanks.

Comment: This issue was not solved, However I switched to scss completely and emmet worked fine for scss and typically stopped writing vanilla css, only writing scss nowadays

Comment: @MoodyOmar it started working after uninstalling tabnine for me.

Answer (score 4):

If none of this works then check the file association, should be CSS.

On the screenshot you can see the bottom bar and selected CSS, if yours not click it and associate .css files with CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reset your settings.json to minimal, like :

```
{
    "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always"    
}
```

Test to see if it works and change the config as you like. [Read the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration) for more info.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. I've already gone through the VS Code emmet docs, It doesn't help me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Uninstall Tabnine.

(or any other autocomplete installed).

## 2. Restart VS code

then add `"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always"`